# Maze solving in python - format of maze text files

Tags: python, python-3.x, maze

Almost certainly being dumb here - I am experimenting with python maze solvers and have been looking to see how various approaches work but am stuck on the format of the actual Maze text files. The code I have borrowed for loading and displaying the maze are as follows

```
def loadMaze():
    readIt = open('Maze2.txt', 'r')
    readLines = readIt.readlines()
    global mazeList
    mazeList = [list(i.strip()) for i in readLines]

def showMaze():
    for i in mazeList:
        mazeprint = ''
    for j in i:
        mazeprint = mazeprint + j
    print(mazeprint)
    print('\n')
```

I am struggling with the format of the text file all that displays is the last line of the maze, I have tried all sorts of different formats, with and without commas, quotes etc etc but no luck.

Please put me out of my misery :0/

Comment: It would be helpful to see an example of what the contents of Maze2.txt look like.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `showMaze()` is indented improperly. Try this:

```
def showMaze():
    for i in mazeList:
        mazeprint = ''
        for j in i:
            mazeprint = mazeprint + j
        print(mazeprint)
        print('\n')
```

The code you provide loops through all the values in `mazeList` and does nothing with it (just reassigns `mazeprint` to an empty string), so at the end `i` is just the last line which you then go through in print. You want to do this for *each* line, so it should be in the `for i ...` loop.

Comment: Thanks for this I will give it a try when I get a minute. :0)